# How do I do multiple string substitions based on a list of files?

Tags: ruby, string, substitution

I have a list of files and a string.

I want to print the string once for every file, with every printed string having a substring substition based on a filename.

I know I can get a list of files by doing `files = Dir.glob("*.jpg")`

I have a string like this:

```
%{here is my very FOO long string}
```

I want to do is this:

For each file, print "here is my very FILENAME long string"

Comment: Note: a `heredoc` is not `%{some string}`. That is a string literal.

Comment: No, not a homework question. I'm just new to programming and ruby. I know it seems pretty basic, but I just couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = %{here is my very FOO long string}
files = Dir.glob("*.jpg").select { |f| File.file?(f) }
files.each { |f| puts str.sub('FOO', f) }
```